# WAMP Server redirects to localhost from ip address to live domain

Tags: wamp

192.168.1.125 this is the ip of my localhost I am using a web based software for a hospital to manage it when I enter ip 192.168.1.125 this will redirect me to the domain cheemaheartcomplex.com this domain has same files and database in it. but the thing is I don't want my ip redirect to the domain

I have checked all the configurations files in wamp